# I have a for-loop in C# I want to run only once

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, boolean

I have a for-loop that I need to call only once as I'm iterating through an array.

```
    public void ChangeClassButton()
    {
        Debug.Log("Changed Class");
        for (int i = 0; i < activeDrum.Length && !changeClassBool; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(activeDrum[i]);
            changeClassText.text = activeDrum[i];
            OscMessage oscM = Osc.StringToOscMessage("/changeClass" + i);
            Debug.Log(Osc.OscMessageToString(oscM));
            oscHandler.Send(oscM);
            changeClassBool = true;
            if (i >= activeDrum.Length)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a seperate function setting the changeClassBool back to false after a set amount of time.

I'm trying to get an iteration on a button press, but when I press the button in the game it just iterates through the whole array. Any suggestions to as what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here. If you didn't want a loop, can't you simply remove the loop? Or are you asking how to make the button step through the iteration one item at a time?

Comment: You want to iterate always through i = 0 or every click increases i by 1?

Comment: If you do not click on button then what is `activeDrum.Length` ? and what is value of changeClassBool ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A for loop might not be the best way to go about this. How about just upping the value when you call the method?

```
private int count = 0;

public void ChangeClassButton()
{
    Debug.Log("Skiftede klasse");
    if(!changeClassBool){
    {
        Debug.Log(activeDrum[count]);
        changeClassText.text = activeDrum[count];
        OscMessage oscM = Osc.StringToOscMessage("/changeClass" + count);
        Debug.Log(Osc.OscMessageToString(oscM));
        oscHandler.Send(oscM);
        changeClassBool = true;
        if (count >= activeDrum.Length)
        {
            count = 0;
        } else{
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as to why it's not working now. You mention that you set `changeClassBool` to false after a certain amount of time. But this loop is run instantly, meaning that it will complete in one frame, no matter how big the loop is. If you want to wait in your loop you can make it a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and add a `yield return null` to make it wait one frame.

But if the only thing you want to do, is to go through this each time you click a button, just using a counter instead of a loop is way less complex and more stable.

Comment: Glad it's what you were looking for, I also added a little explanation about what went wrong with the for loop, just in case you need this for a different use case in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use the `while` loop.

```
int i = 0;
        public void ChangeClassButton()
        {
            while (!changeClassBool)
            {
                Debug.Log(activeDrum[i]);
                changeClassText.text = activeDrum[i];
                OscMessage oscM = Osc.StringToOscMessage("/changeClass" + i);
                Debug.Log(Osc.OscMessageToString(oscM));
                oscHandler.Send(oscM);
                changeClassBool = true;
                if (i >= activeDrum.Length)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
```

This loop runs once.

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is to iterate through this array (activeDrum) only once why not use "for each"? it might also save you the extra boolean you have in this for loop.